# Concurrent programing in plain C - Windows / Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, concurrency

I have a function, lets say, `callMe(args)`. I would like to be able to call my function 100 times in the same time (concurrent programing). My function is written in plain C. I want to make it concurrent for Windows and Linux.

Is there any built in support for this in standard C library? Or can you provide some advices, how should I do this in Linux/Windows?

Is `pthread` good for Linux environments for this?

Comment: I have used pthreads on windows with no problems.  MSVC supports OpenMP 2.5.  ICC for MSVC supports OpenMP (4.0 I think).  You could also use SDL_threads (which is almost the same as pthreads) which is cross platform.  You could also use Qt-threads which is cross-platform.

Answer (score 5):

You can't write a concurrent program in pure standard [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). Concurrent programming is not in standard C99; it requires some operating system specific libraries. However, the latest  [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) standard (which has very few implementations today, February 2014 - I know none!) is beginning to add support for threads. On Linux systems I would suggest today to stick to [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

You could use a cross-platform library (like [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) from [GTK](http://gtk.org/)) to ease porting between Windows and Linux. On Linux, it is wrapping pthreads.

<sup>I don't know Windows, but Glib -and GTK for GUI applications- is rumored to enable source-compatible coding between Windows & Linux</sup>

If your computation is embarrassingly [data parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_parallelism) (like some matrix numerical computations are), consider also [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) (notably because it can run on [GPGPUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU)) or [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP). If it fits in a [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing_in_computer_clusters) paradigm, consider [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface)

<sup>OpenCL, OpenMP, MPI are rumored to enable source-compatible coding for Linux and for Windows.</sup>

In [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) (which is a different language than C) you have [thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) support, and the GCC 4.8.2 compiler is supporting them quite well. And [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Boost](http://boost.org/) is a cross-platform C++ library, notably wrapping concurrent primitives.

Whatever concurrent mechanism you are using, beware of [synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29) issues.

<sup>You always have synchronization with concurrency, at least to wait for the results of each concurrent or parallel sub-computation</sup>

Comment: There are a few attempts to port pthreads spec to Windows too, so it would make sense to prefer it over windows specific mechanisms

Comment: Since I dont share any data between function calls, should I care about synchronization at all? Ok, so for linux I can use `pthreads` - how about Windows? Is openMP good for Windows too? Or maybe you know abot `operating system specific libraries` for Windows? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different functions for different platforms.
Its similar like different browsers uses different kind of css property names.

So for linux/mac you can use `pthread`
And for windows you use `CreateThread`